# How to add user input to array

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader ();
        double money = 0; //Cash Variable
        int Choice = 0; //Menu Choice
        Scanner AccountIn = new Scanner(System.in);  //Scanner for AccountNumbers
        ArrayList<String> AccountNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
        String accountValue = "";


                int x = 1;    

do{     
                 try{   
                    System.out.println("Create Account Number");
                    accountValue = AccountIn.nextLine();
                    if(accountValue.length()>0 && accountValue.length()<=9){ 
                       accountValue.add(AccountNumber); //Add UserInput to arrayList

                                System.out.println("Final Amount:"  +money);
```

I am trying to add the user input 'accountValue' into the ArrayList 'AccountNumber' but it doesnt display when I choose to view it.

Comment: at least format your code if you expect others to volunteer their time to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
    accountValue.add(AccountNumber);
```

With:

```
   AccountNumber.add(accountValue);
```

The `AccountNumber` is the ArrayList and `accountValue`is the value to store.

Comment: Ohh wow cant believe I didnt notice that:s, thank you anyways.